# Tomcat and Wildfly (erstwhile JBoss) Support?

Tags: webserver, jboss

Would these app servers work in Ubuntu? I have used tomcat in an Ubuntu image in AWS. Not sure about wildfly. Thank you

Comment: you just download the `.zip` file, unzip and read docs.  It's not really in a repo.  (nothing mainstream at least.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes they will. WildFly can definitively run on Ubuntu